# Sql-Server Create login not working

Tags: .net, sql-server, c#-4.0, ado.net

Hi I am just starting out in learning C# by reading Visual:Step by Step. I am at chapter 25 witch starts teaching ADO.NET. At the begining of the chapter there is a step by step exercise that walk you throught creating a login to sql-server. I am given this statement:

```
CREATE LOGIN [computer\login] FROM WINDOWS
```

When I first started to try to login my computer name was Aly-PC and my login Aly. I have changed my login username to Alexandru and restarted my computer in an effort to make this work but it still doesn't. I am geting this error:

[image]

I am posting also from where I got the computer name and userame because maybe I am not geting the right ones. If that is true where should I look for them?

Computer Name My Computer -> Properties:

[image]

Login Control Panel\User Accounts and Family Safety\User Accounts :

[image]

Answer (score -1):

SQL server (SQLExpress in your case) has users and logins - these are 2 separate entities, you have to create SQL server user in order to assign (create) a login for it.

Comment: I am kind of new on this do you know any tutorial that might help?

Comment: Create user http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463
and then create login
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751
This should do it.

Comment: Yet another thing - it looks like you are using **incorrect** (forward instead of back) slash, this may be the actual cause of your error

Comment: I have replaced it with the backslash now the error seems to say I am not using the corect names

Comment: As you are using local user try it **without** computer name, i.e.  
`CREATE LOGIN Alexandru FROM WINDOWS`

Comment: @GermannArlington You create logins before you create users. Users belong to databases, not logins.